# Javascript wait for nested loops to finish

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, async-await

Here is my problem :
I have nested loops for data treatment (this is a simplified version from what I have :

```js
 const dataTreatment = (formData) => {
   for (let i = 0; i < formData.agencies.length; i++) {
     for(const type in formData.formTypes) {
       switch(type) {
         case 'address':
           formData[type].forEach(async (item) => {
             await axios.post('', {});
           }
           break;
         case 'schedules':
           formData[type].forEach(async (item) => {
             await axios.post('', {});
           }
           break;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

In another file, I execute this function ahead of others and want it to wait for loops to finished but it executes the following functions.

```js
const submit = async () => {
  await dataTreatment();
  await doSomethingAfter();
}
```

My problem is it doesn't wait and execute "doSomethingAfter" right after. I think i'm missing something about loops and async functions...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `await` calls to work, your function needs to be declared as `async`.

```
 const dataTreatment = async (formData) => { // note the async word
   for (let i = 0; i < formData.agencies.length; i++) {
     for(const type in formData.formTypes) {
       switch(type) {
         case 'address':
           formData[type].forEach(async (item) => {
             await axios.post('', {});
           }
           break;
         case 'schedules':
           formData[type].forEach(async (item) => {
             await axios.post('', {});
           }
           break;
       }
     }
   }
 }

const submit = async () => {
  await dataTreatment();
  await doSomethingAfter();
}
```

The same is also true of the `doSomethingAfter` function and needs to be declared `async`.